# I want to create an Android activity that takes in a user given temperature and convert between F to C or C to F

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My `MainActivity.java` file looks like this:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    public void onClick(View v)
        {   
            EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String s = e1.toString();
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(s);

            double finalTemp = 0.0;

            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.radio0 :
                    if(checked)
                    {
                        finalTemp = (temp * (9/5)) + 32;
                    }

                case R.id.radio1 :
                    if(checked)
                    {
                        finalTemp = (temp - 32) * (5/9);
                    }
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "The Converted Temperature is: " + finalTemp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
```

There are two radio buttons, and one is C to F another is F to C. The user will enter a double number and will check either of the boxes and will hit "convert" button and a toast message will appear with the converted temperature. But as soon as I am entering a value and hitting the convert button, the application is crashing.

I am new to android. Please help me. If possible give me some basic concepts of radio buttons and normal buttons. I am not new to java though.

Thanks...

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: My bet is , it is crashing here double temp = Double.parseDouble(s);

Answer (score 1):

You got your onClick() method all wrong. And also when getting string from EditText use `edittext.getText().toString()`. The way you took it will make your application crashes at this line  `double temp = Double.parseDouble(s);`
Try something like this.

```
  public void onClick(View v)
        {   
            EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String s = e1.getText().toString(); 
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(s);

            double finalTemp = 0.0;
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroupId);
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            switch(selectedId )
            {
                case R.id.radio0 :
                         finalTemp = (temp * (9/5)) + 32;
                       break;

                case R.id.radio1 :
                        finalTemp = (temp - 32) * (5/9);
                       break;
             }

            Toast.makeText(this, "The Converted Temperature is: " + finalTemp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
```

And dont forget your `break;` in `switch` statements.

Or you can try this way:

```
public void onClick(View v)
        {   
            EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String s = e1.getText().toString(); 
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(s);

            double finalTemp = 0.0;


           RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
           RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
           if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
               finalTemp = (temp * (9/5)) + 32;
            } else {
               finalTemp = (temp - 32) * (5/9);
           }  
      }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. That helped in running my app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now I am facing a different problem. When I enter a number and click any of the checkboxes, I get the result only for the radio0 checked.

Comment: The radio1 checked always gives answer 0.0

Comment: My layout file is given below... Please help.

Comment: <RadioGroup
        

android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    

android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    

android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    

android:layout_marginTop="42dp" >

Comment: <RadioButton
     

android:id="@+id/radio0"

    

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     

android:text="@string/faren" />
     
     

<RadioButton
     

android:id="@+id/radio1"
    

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="@string/centi" />

    

</RadioGroup>

Comment: RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1); will do, I think.

Comment: Nope. Still if I am converting 43 C to F, answer is coming to be 75, and for 43 F to C, its 0.0.
Both of these values are wrong by the formula I am putting up.. :(

Comment: Seems that you have some calculations issues. Refer to this example. It is doing the same thing  http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/convert-temperature-example-in-android-development/

Answer (score 0):

Inside onClick method replace String s = e1.toString() with String s = e1.getText().toString() statement.

Answer (score 0):

Move e1 inside on create method

```
EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

In the onClick method for the button do

```
String s = e1.getText().toString();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this code, may help you:

```
String s1=e1.getText().toString();
```

and check the `s1.len>0`
hit the button  convert the answer otherwise the don't do anything....